# How to implement a range of constant predefined "states" of a property?

Tags: c#, types, constants

I have a property `LegalCaseStatus`. My intention is to make the property to accept a predefined range of approved values. The range must be visible and unchanged throughtout my program. Here's an example of the list:

```
Plaintiff
Defendant
Third Party
Debitor
Creditor
Petitioner
```

So, the best way I could think of is to declare a static class, and fill it with corresponding constants:

```
public static class Participants
{
    public const byte 
        Piaintiff = 0, 
        Defendant = 1, 
        ThirdParty = 2, 
        Debitor= 3, 
        Creditor = 4, 
        Petitioner = 5;
}
```

so after using a namespace I could just do:

```
public byte LegalCaseStasus = Plaintiff;
```

the only problem is, since it's just a `byte` member it'll accept anything that is `byte`:

```
LegalCaseStatus = 99; // ok
LegalCaseStatus = SomeOtherByteConstant; // ok
```

How do I protect the member `LegalCaseStatus`? Is my solution generally correct?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect use case for enum ?

Comment: Did you hear about enums? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum. You can easily predefine a set of named constants of the underlying integral numeric type.

Comment: You can use an enum, as others say, but one word of warning - they still won't prevent assignment of undefined values in the enum. So you should still [check the incoming value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?view=net-5.0#System_Enum_IsDefined__1___0_) in your property setter and throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use enums - *An enum is a special "class" that represents a group of constants (unchangeable/read-only variables).* Sounds like the thing you describe in your question:

```
public enum Participants
{
        Piaintiff = 0,
        Defendant = 1,
        ThirdParty = 2,
        Debitor = 3,
        Creditor = 4,
        Petitioner = 5
}
```

After the enum definition you can use it exactly the way you want to:

```
Participants LegalCaseStasus = Participants.ThirdParty;
LegalCaseStasus = 99;   // ERROR      
byte underlying_value = (byte)LegalCaseStasus; // value == 2
```

Note: The underlying value of an `enum` is `int`! When you cast to `byte` you need to make sure there are no predefined values that exceed the `byte` limit.

Comment: @IgorCheglakov this syntax performs a cast. Cast is a method by which a value is converted from one data type to another. In this specific case we cast a variable of type `Participants` to `int`.